# Apache automatically redirects to different file

Tags: apache, redirect

When a file is not found on my apache server, the server automatically redirects (http 301) to a file with a similar name.

For example if the file

```
http://myserver.com/files/image012.jpg
```

is requested, but does not exist, the server redirects to

```
http://myserver.com/files/image021.jpg
```

(which does exist).

How can I prevent this?

Comment: It depends on how your apache is configured.Check .htaccess files and/or config files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server probably has automatic spelling check activated by default. 
Try adding the following line to your .htaccess file

```
CheckSpelling off
```